# Text changing animation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, setinterval

I am trying to create a changing text for every 3 seconds. But it seems just to run once and then it stops doing anything. My code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="output">
  <h2>True Multi-Purpose Theme for
     <span class="changingtext">Business</span> 
     and More
   </h2>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let newText = document.querySelector('.changingtext')

setInterval(function() {
  if (newText.innerHTML = 'Business'){
    newText.innerHTML = 'Agencies';
  }
  else if (newText.innerHTML = "Agencies"){
    newText.innerHTML = 'Startups';
  }
  else {
    newText.innerHTML = 'Business';
  }
}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using **assignation** instead of **comparaison** in your `if`

**WRONG**

```
 if(newText.innerHTML = 'Business'){
```

**CORRECT**

```
 if (newText.innerHTML === 'Business') {
```

```js
let newText = document.querySelector('.changingtext')

setInterval(function() {
  if (newText.innerHTML === 'Business') {
    newText.innerHTML = 'Agencies';
  } else if (newText.innerHTML === "Agencies") {
    newText.innerHTML = 'Startups'
  } else {
    newText.innerHTML = 'Business'
  }

}, 3000)
```

```html
<div class="output">
  <h2>True Multi-Purpose Theme
    <be>
      for
      <span class="changingtext">Business</span> and More
  </h2>
</div>
```

---

Also, the following could be better :

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.changingtext')

const texts = [
  'Business',
  'Agencies',
  'Startups',
];

function nextText() {
   const actualTextIndex = texts.findIndex(x => text.innerText === x);
   
   const newTextIndex = actualTextIndex + 1 === texts.length ? 0 : actualTextIndex + 1;
   
   text.innerText = texts[newTextIndex];
}

setInterval(nextText, 3000)
```

```html
<div class="output">
  <h2>True Multi-Purpose Theme
    <be>
      for
      <span class="changingtext">Business</span> and More
  </h2>
</div>
```

You can improve it again by :

- Creating an utility function that will work in standalone getting the selector, the time between a text change and the list of texts to loop from

Gl